# repeating instruction What's wrong in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, winjs

the code is sample but the resut seems not logical at all;
Here the code:

```
function lap_validation(event) {
    if (event.srcElement == document.getElementById("Suivant")) {
        console.log("Suivant fired " + event.srcElement);
        document.getElementById("msg").textContent = " Voulez vous vraiment passer à la lettre  suivante ?";
        console.log(document.getElementById("msg").textContent);
        var buyButton = document.getElementById("test");
        document.getElementById("confirmFlyout").winControl.show(buyButton);
        document.getElementById("no").addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.getElementById("confirmFlyout").winControl.hide();
                console.log("hide");

        }, false);
        document.getElementById("ok").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //next();
            //document.getElementById("confirmFlyout").winControl.hide();
            console.log("click on ok from flyout");
        }, false);

    }
}
```

When I click th button "Suivant", a flyout will appear when i click ok button   for the first time i have this output:

```
Suivant fired [object HTMLButtonElement]
Voulez vous vraiment passer à la lettre  suivante ?
click on ok from flyout
```

when i click the second time :

```
Suivant fired [object HTMLButtonElement]
Voulez vous vraiment passer à la lettre  suivante ?
click on ok from flyout
click on ok from flyout
```

the third:

```
Suivant fired [object HTMLButtonElement]
 Voulez vous vraiment passer à la lettre  suivante ?
click on ok from flyout
click on ok from flyout
click on ok from flyout
```

I don't understand why it repeat the instruction of the Flyout's button(the same when i click "no" button ).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: it is likely that your code is registering the event listener for ok button each time lap_validation is called, and hence - it is getting called 1, 2, 3 times etc. suggest register the event listener outside this method in the ready event handler for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering the events using onclick have flip side as well. it may override other registered event handler in more involved application and then, end up chasing how events are not coming in some flow. It might be best to follow the practices of having a method `_initializeEventHandlers()` in winjs page. invoke it from onready event handler and register all event handlers at this place. if needed in some cases (like share contract events), override `unload()` method to deregister the handlers.

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/mypage/mypage.html',
{
    ready: function onready(element, options)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = options;
        this._initialize();
    },
    _initialize: function initialize()
    {
        this._initializeEventHandlers();
    },
    _initializeEventHandlers: function initializeEventHandlers()
    {
        // all element with id can be access by the variable names 
        ok.addEventListener('click', this._onokclick.bind(this));
        no.addEventListener('click', this._onnoclick.bind(this));
    },
    _onxyz: function _onxyzhandler(event)
    {
        confirmFlyout.winControl.show(buyButton);
    },
    _onokclick: function onokclick(event)
    {
        console.log('ok button in flyout clicked');
    },
    _onnoclick: function onnoclick(event)
    {
        confirmFlyout.winControl.hide();
        console.log('no button in flyout clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding a new event listener every time. The easiest fix is to change...
`document.getElementById("ok").addEventListener("click", function () {...`
to
`document.getElementById("ok").onclick = function() {...`

The big advantage to addEventListener is that it allows you to add multiple event listeners. That can bite you as you can see here. You're adding a new event listener every time. If you use onclick instead, then you are *replacing* the event listener each time so only one event listener will ever exist for the click event.

Answer (score 0):

As the sample uses console.log() for every output the solution to this case is clear:
Everytime you click on `ok` you call `console.log("click on ok from flyout");` and thus get another line written into the console.

If your real code doesn't use console.log, please provide us with a sample for that – your code behaves the way it should behave.

Comment: i am using console.log() just for testing , but in real case i have a function next() that it will be called instead , i think that i have provlem in this next function but when i replced it by consloe , it's the same

Comment: Please edit your initial question and provide a sample of your real code - because your sample works exactly the way it should work, I just don't see any problem here?